# Retrieve attributes in generic method for Enums

Tags: c#, generics, enums

Using the following Enum:

```
public enum AuthorizeRole
{
    // The Name is used to Seed the database 
    // The description is used to display a friendly name to the user

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    Undefined,

    [Display(Name = "Administrator", Description = "Administrator")]
    Administrator,

    [Display(Name = "Customer", Description = "Customer")]
    Customer,

    [Display(Name = "Business User", Description = "Business User")]
    BusinessUser
}
```

I wrote the following class to be able to retrieve all the values of an Enum:

```
public static class Enum<T> 
  where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues()
    {
        var result = ((T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
            .ToList();

        return result;
    }
}
```

And an Extension method to retrieve attribute metadata:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetName(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DisplayAttribute[] attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false) as DisplayAttribute[];

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
        {
            return attributes[0].Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

So now it's trivial to do:

```
foreach (var role in Enun<AuthorizeRole>.GetValues())
{
  string roleName = role.GetName();
}
```

I'm at a loss how to create the method `GetNames()` (It may not be possible?):

```
public static class Enum<T> 
  where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetNames()
    {
        var result = ((T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
            // at this point since T is not typeof(System.Enum) it fails
            .Select(t => t.GetName()) 
            .ToList();

        return result;
    }
}
```

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ntnwsK)

Comment: Sadly, you can't constrain to Enum using generics. C# does not allow it, although the CLR does. You might want to look at Jon Skeet's Unconstrained Melody project, which works around it my manipulating the IL: http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/

Comment: Although cool, I don't think I'd go that route just to allow writing a simple extension method.  I was hoping that I could avoid the entire Enum issue since I'm just reflecting on the value to find an attribute, it doesn't necessarily need to be cast as Enum (I'd hope).

Comment: In that case, you might be better off casting to Enum. You lose the 'purity' of the generic code, and move the error-catching from compile time to runtime, but it might be the best you can do otherwise.

Comment: By all means add that (with code) as an answer, if no body else has any bright ideas, at least the question and answer would be here for others.

Comment: The best I've done is to add a static constructor to `Enum<T>` that checks `<T>`. That way the check is done at runtime, but only _once_ per type `T` used. You can have it throw an exception (which will result in a `TypeInitializationException`) and prevent any real usage of any invalid `Enum<TNotAnEnumType>` type. EDIT: That way you're guaranteed that any use of that class will be valid (at least within any of its method bodies)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Nice. At least that way you're catching the error as *early as possble* at runtime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was using `.ToString()` for reflecting the value I got it working.

```
public static class Enum<T>
  where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
    {
        var result = ((T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
            .Select(t => new
            {
                failName = t.ToString(),
                displayAttribute = (typeof(T)
                    .GetField(t.ToString())
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false) 
                      as DisplayAttribute[]).FirstOrDefault()
            })
            .Select(a => a.displayAttribute != null 
              ? a.displayAttribute.Name: a.failName)
            .ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

[DotNetFiddle - Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wffnnb)